# rendering JSON response urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am having trouble handling a JSONP response to an ajax call to a website. My intention is to have the the results (url's) of the news items displayed on a page so when a user clicks on each link, he or she would be directed to the page containing the story. However, that is not happening.

Though I was able to display the result as an unordered list. Instead when I click on the links, I get directed to a local folder with a file not found message.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url:"http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all/.jsonp",
    data: {"api-key":"uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu"},
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    type: 'GET',    
    success:function(mydata){
      $.each(mydata.results, function(i, value){
         $("ul").append('<li>'+'<a href="">'+mydata.results[i].url+'</a>'+ '</li>');
         $("ul li a").attr("href", "mydata.results[i].url");
      });
      //alert("Success");
    }, 
    error:function(){
       alert("Error");
    },
    });
  });
```

Comment: You have a typo: `$("ul li a").attr("href", mydata.results[i].url);` remove the quotes around the variable.

Comment: Why are you adding the `href` *after* you create the `a` tag? You're also replacing every `href` with the same value on each loop. Why not put it in when you create the `a` tag string? Also, since you have the `mydata...` part in quotes, that's a string literal that's put in that attribute, not it's related variable.

Comment: Thanks guys.. I tried doing the following but I kept getting the file not found message..I am not sure why..                $("ul").append('<li>'+'<a href="mydata.results[i].url">'+mydata.results[i].url+'</a>'+ '</li>');

Comment: @user3681587 Because you are including `mydata.results[i].url` as a string. If you inspect the output, it will be exactly that instead of the url you're trying to use from the json object. See my comment above or Parv's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replacing your code by this probably will help

```
$.each(mydata.results, function(i, value){
                 $("ul").append('<li>'
                 +'<a href="'+mydata.results[i].url+'">'+mydata.results[i].url+'</a>'
                 + '</li>');
              });
```

things you are doing wrong
1. changing href value of every `a` for each iteration of the loop.
2. setting string value (`"mydata.results[i].url"`) in the `href` instead of 
`mydata.results[i].url`